# How to bind layout with several qualifiers

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I have 2 layouts: one for v19+ and another for earlier versions. They contain different views with different ids. How can I say Android DataBinding framework that I want to work with both layouts? It generates views only for one layout (selects randomly).

layout/temp_view.xml :

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="block"
            type="ru.temp.model.content.blocks.WebMediaBlock" />

        <import type="ru.temp.model.Types.ProviderTypes" />

    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:background="@android:color/white">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/provider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/size5"
            android:src="@{ProviderTypes.fromString(block.provider).getResId()}" />
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

layout-v19/temp_view.xml :

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="block"
            type="ru.temp.model.content.blocks.WebMediaBlock" />

        <import type="ru.temp.model.Types.ProviderTypes" />

    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:background="@android:color/white">
        <ru.temp.utils.EmbedView
            android:id="@+id/media_embed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ru.temp.structure.static_material.CreditsView
            android:id="@+id/credits_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Update:

Finally I've found out the root of the problem. I don't know why but it does not generate *BindingImpl files when use minSdkVersion 21. If specify earlier versions it works as said @yigit

Comment: You can also check [this](http://chintanrathod.com/develop_apps_faster_using_data_binding_part2/) tutorial for your reference.

Comment: It does not cover the problem details

Answer (score 1):

Data binding will generate a base class that serves as a common interface for both (the variables). Data binding will take care of creating the right instance when you call `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(activity, R.layout.tmp_view`).

For instance, in your example, it will generate

`TempViewBinding`, `TempViewBindingImpl` and `TempViewBindingV19Impl`.
You can check these classes inside `<app module>/build/intermediates/classes/<your package>/databinding/` after you compile.

`TempViewBinding` is the base class and it will have the combination of variables and views for each layout. 
If you are not seeing them in the IDE, might be an auto-completion bug in AS (please file a bug).

Comment: Unfortunately it does not generate such Impl classes. And I can't find the information you provided on the official docs. Can't determine what I'm doing wrong

Comment: if you can upload a sample project, i'm happy to look at it

Comment: sorry for a late response but it had much time to detect the problem. Please check the update of the head. And look at the test project (master branch) https://github.com/rchugunov/buzzer In the current version databinding does not generate Impl files. But if you set minSdkVersion 15 in  build.gradle it will do!

Comment: you are using android-apt. try reporting it there.